# Set a databricks python variable with a %sql statement

Tags: python, sql, azure, databricks

The code in `cell 1` works just fine.

#### The problem

I just don't know the correct keywords to search to see how I can make the code in `cells 2 & 3` work. Basically, in a `%sql` cell, can I select into a variable that can be later used in a `python` cell? I realize this may not even be possible. Cheers!

`cell 1`

```py
ds = spark.sql("select * from duamonds")
display(ds)
```

`cell 2`

```sql
%sql
select * from diamonds
```

`cell 3`

```py
display({ sql result })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be done. However, you can do this:

`Cell1`

```
sqlresult= sqlContext.sql("select * from diamonds")
```

`Cell2`

```
display(sqlresult)
```

You can find more details on using SQL with dataframes [HERE](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/3137082781873852/3704545280501166/1264763342038607/latest.html).

Comment: Thank you. But can I do it within a `%sql` cell so I get the SQL fidelity?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the SQL statement you are trying to execute? You should be able to write any SQL statement within the triple quotes provided in the code example in my answer. And it is all SQL language.

Comment: Any statement, honestly. But in notebooks, the editing experience is more rich & the highlighting helps a lot - if for nothing other than simpler debugging & verification. My goal is to use `%SQL` to write the query, but then put the results, not just in the notebook visual output, but into a variable usable in subsequent Python cells. I think I am asking for something that cannot be done.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right, it cannot be done. %SQL will just help visualize the results not assign the results to a variable (like you need). Similar to a print("this is a test").

Answer (score 0):

It CAN be done:

According to the cell in my DB right now (runtime 11):

`SQL cell result stored as PySpark data frame _sqldf.` [Learn more](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-code.html#implicit-sql-df)